# how find the nearest iframes with ffprobe?

Tags: ffmpeg, iframe, ffprobe

I wonder if can find the nearest iframes from certain position(might be certain seconds) in Video file with ffprobe or ffmpeg.

Is it possible? The result what I want is seconds unit position of frames.

My command is `ffprobe -show_frames -select_streams v -print_format json=c=1 Z63902_5_130719.ts | grep "I" | grep "\"pkt_dts_time\""`. Since there is only a capital 'I' in that json, I grep only "I". My problem is that this is too slow. My final goal is get iframe positions from RTSP protocol and make list. If it goes to RTSP, it will be much slower than now.

How can I solve this?

Comment: See my answer in the linked question, and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @slhck Thanks for answer. But I could not try that answer, because when I use the command which posted in your link, it shows that "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('". And Actually I am using full-scan(?) to find keyframes, the problem is it is too slow. I command that ffprobe and grep, and it takes 3 minutes to gather iframe positions from 10 minutes length Video. Is there any way to improve speed? Thanks again

Comment: I am using -print_format option, otherwise when execute grep command it just get "pict_type : I" only.

Comment: @slhck I found a better way to list iframe positions. when I use "-show_frames" option, it takes 2 minutes and 59 seconds. But somehow when I use other option, It finished in several seconds. I do not know why but it is certain using "show_packets" option is faster with same result. Thanks again. Should I delete this Question or not. I will follow your judgement:D

Comment: If you want, you can post your own solution on the other question as an answer, and we just let this question stay. You don't need to delete it.

Comment: @slhck Thanks:D Since I am thinking you are such an expert of ff- series. If you do not mind, can I ask one more question? I am working with TS format files. And as you know, TS packet has fixed size which is 188 bytes. But when I use "-show_packets" option and input my ts file, its size is very various. I do not know why this size is so. Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Not sure – can you post a new question with more details and sample output, perhaps? Thanks!